# Remote Development SSH - No Linux Installation Found on the Selected Machine

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, jetbrains-gateway

I'm trying to connect SSH but it returns the error that there is no Linux installed on the machine on PhpStorm (IDE by JetBrains).

I use the Fedora 36 distribution. When I start the project via SSH through the remote field, it connects normally:

[image: step 1]

Now, if I try to create a new project only to connect and start working within the IDE itself according to the folders, it gives me the error that Linux is not installed on the machine:

[image: step 2]

Return error:

[image: step 3]

How can I manipulate the folders and codes of a project equally VSCode SSH extension? In SSH through the IDE itself as if it were a project from 0 ? Is it possible in PhpStorm?

Comment: What is your remote Linux architecture is? Is it ARM?

Comment: To elaborate on the above: linux ARM is not yet supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-1580